# Detectar los MS de respuesta y hacer un switch PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código

```
function conexions($domain){
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file){
        $status = -1;
    } else {
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}

$resp = conexions('socialbooks.66ghz.com');
echo $resp;
```

y la siguiente duda, ¿Es posible detectar los MS de respuesta y a base de eso saber si la conexión es estable o no?

ej : si tiene entre 50 ms y 350 ms que use un echo para decir conexion perfecta

Intenté hacer switch y no sirve

Comment: intente tu código y funciona perfectamente. Tu código regresa -1 si no funciona el dominio y la cantidad de ms para accederlo si funciona. En que no te funciona ? Estarás detrás de un FW que te bloquea ciertos canales de red ? Usas algún proxy o puerta de enlaze quizás que tienes que recalcar en tu código ?

Comment: No, el problema es que quiero hacer que si tienes entre 50 - 350 ms use la variable Estado y le ponga el string por ejemplo Funciona Perfecto

Comment: algo como if ($status >= 50 and $status <= 350) return "Perfecto"; elseif ($status < 50) return "muy rapido"; else return "lento"; ?

Comment: ya gracias, la idea es que detecte la velocidad de la conexión y muestre si esta estable o no

Comment: No pongas resuelto a tu pregunta. Si encontraste una solucion, por favor agregala como respuesta, y despues podes aceptar la misma.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if ($status >= 50 and $status <= 350) return "Perfecto"; elseif ($status < 50) return "muy rapido"; else return "lento";
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, ayudanos agregando una explicación del código para que sea de utilidad a todos los miembros de la comunidad, revisa [answer],saludos.